# How can I start a firefox window from perl with a defined size?

Tags: perl, firefox, command-line

Using perl in Win7, I want to display an html file in a new firefox window specifying the initial window size. I used the command:

```
$cmd=`\\progra~2\\Mozill~1\\firefox.exe -height 400 -width 800 -new-window tmp.htm`;
```

I get a new window, correctly showing the contents of the file, but the height and weight I specified are ignored in favor of what appears to be the default. Moving the parameters to the end of the command makes no difference.

How can I get firefox to set the window size as specified?

Comment: Do you already have an instance of Firefox open?  If so, it looks like the height and width options will be ignored.  I found a user forum question about this [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/977269).  When I tried specifying window size with no Firefox instances running, it seemed to use that size.  If a Firefox instance was already open and running, it seemed to ignore those options.  That might be the root cause of what you're experiencing.

Comment: What I recall from my similar attempts of a few years ago agrees with [dasgar](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6027771/dasgar)'s comment.  I can't reproduce the links I found then but I think it's a bug of sorts which is years old, whereby the geometry arguments are ignored. It must be possible to set it using your window manager but that is something else.

Comment: Right! Thanks! I closed all my firefox windows, and it worked! Previously I simply minimized them and it didn't work. Maybe I'll try a different browser.

Comment: @dasgar: Please add it as an answer as your comment has solved OP's issue.

Answer (score 0):

dasgar and zdim are right. When I closed all firefox instances, the command-line argument set the size correctly. It was not enough to minimize the firefox windows. This appears to be a persistent firefox bug.

What I have done is call Chrome instead. That works fine, since I rarely use Chrome. I haven't checked to see whether an existing open Chrome window would give the same problem as firefox.